# ¿Como conectar nginx con otro servidor remoto?

Tags: nginx

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme a encontrar el camino para resolver esto ...

Tengo en un servidor (A) un despliegue de una aplicación web que usa Nginx para servir contenido media (imágenes, pdf, etc) y tengo un servidor (B) del cual necesito servir contenido media.

**¿Con qué directivas de configuración de Nginx conecto mi servidor (A) con (B) para que pueda enviar el contenido del servidor (B) a mi aplicación web?**

*PD. La carpeta que tiene el contenido en el servidor (B) esta protegida por usuario y contraseña
(No se donde colocar estos datos en la configuración de Nginx)*

Comment: sistemas operativos de A y B ? B sólo sirve archivos ? que protocolo usa B para compartir archivos (http. ftp. nfs, smb/cifs)? la idea es usar B como CDN o es un share de servidor a servidor (ej: de punto de vista del cliente A es el que sirve los archivos)?

Comment: Hola, el sistema operativo de (A) es Ubuntu 16.04 y el de (B) es Windows Server 2008 y usa SMB en ambos casos tanto sirven archivos  como tienen aplicaciones desplegadas. Todas las ideas son bienvenidas!

Comment: si querés balancear la carga montas un servidor http en B, y el cliente se comunica directamente con B (onda CDN). si A va a servir archivos de B como si fueran propios podes montar la carpeta compartida en el filesystem de A . para hacerlo permanente:  https://askubuntu.com/q/657512/754957

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarías tener nginx corriendo en ambos servidores. Si

- A sirve la aplicación y
- B sirve los estáticos

Lo que puedes hacer es, en el servidor A:

```
# las peticiones dentro del directorio `media` se piden via proxy
location ~ ^/media/ {
    proxy_pass http://servidorB;
}

# el resto se pide normalmente
location / {
    # la cofiguración para el resto de los archivos
}
```

En el servidor B me parece que los archivos también tendrían que estar dentro de un subdirectorio `media`.

Ahora, dices que para acceder a esos archivos necesitas usuario y contraseña. Si estamos hablando de un Basic Auth (se abre un diálogo del browser y no un diálogo en el HTML) puedes enviar un header `Authorization` al hacer el proxy pass.

Supongamos que las credenciales son `miuser` y `mipass`.

Codificando el string `miuser:mipass` en base64 te da `bWl1c2VyOm1pcGFzcw==`

```js
console.log(btoa('miuser:mipass'));
```

La autenticación entonces debe enviar el header `Authorization` con el valor `Basic bWl1c2VyOm1pcGFzcw==`.

```
location ~ ^/media/ {
   proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic bWl1c2VyOm1pcGFzcw=="; 
   proxy_pass http://servidorB;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo checare de inmediato ;)